# ¿Como conectar MeteorJs con MongoDB remoto?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Hola a todos tengo mi Aplicación **MeteorJS** que se conecta a su base de datos, pero necesito conectarla a mi **Robomongo** externo, es decir mi **MongoDB** corre en un puerto distinto

Algunos avances:

en mi consola de windows :

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/basedatos meteor run
```

Comment: agrega el código que has elaborado, de la misma manera agrega mayores detalles, porque tal y como está tu pregunta, tiene alto chance de ser cerrada. Saludos

Comment: La he editado, gracias por tu observacion

Comment: necesitas conectarte a 2 base de datos al mismo tiempo?

Comment: No, solo a una..

Comment: robomongo es un admin tool, el servicio es mongodb, cambia la cadena de conexión en tu app de meteor (que por cierto, sigo sin ver en tu pregunta) saludos :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asegurate de definir tu variable de entorno `MONGO_URL` con la ruta de tu base de datos antes de ejecutar el comando meteor.

Tu variable debe estar definida asi:

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb://ip_de_tu_servidor:puerto/nombre_de_tu_bd
```

ejemplo

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/meteor
```

confirma la ruta almacenada con `echo $MONGO_URL`

Answer (score 0):

Para no estar colocando la url de tu conexion cuando ejecutas la aplicacion te recomiendo crear un archivo de variables de entorno ejemplo env.sh

y colocar dentro del archivo el contenido siguiente:

```
# This .sh file will be sourced before starting your application.
# You can use it to put environment variables you want accessible
# to the server side of your app by using process.env.MY_VAR
#
# Example:
# export MONGO_URL="mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp-development"
# export ROOT_URL="http://localhost:3000"
```